# SSRS export to EXCEL[direct]

Tags: sql, excel, reporting-services

Can I create SSRS report that directly exports to excel without viewing in the SSRS module?

When clicking View Report in SSRS the excel should get generated?

Using VS2005.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have a query that has to process 10,00,000 records and uses SQL procedure at the backend. The VS 2005 SSRS just throws outofMemory exception. Is there any solution?

Comment: why not create a stored procedure or a view that returns the result directly into Excel instead of going through SSRS?

Comment: You can use a URL to export directly to Excel see here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/export-a-report-using-url-access?view=sql-server-ver15) However, it sounds like you should be using something other than SSRS. As Harry suggested, create Stored Proc to do all the work then use something like SSIS to export the results. Finally, why are you using an unsupported 16 year old version of VS?